# Typo mistakes in input still meet conditions for text based RPG game with Python 2.7 on UNIX

Tags: python, if-statement, input, while-loop, text-based

I've been learning how to code for a month now using the "Learn Python The Hard Way" tutorial.
So far it's been a lot of fun.
I challenged myself in creating a text based RPG game.

I am currently re-writing the code for improved readability and maintenance.

I am facing a problem:

If I type in the choice input "open heaby door" (notice the typo mistake), the conditions are still met and I get the expected print as if it didn't have the typo mistake.

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Thanks for the help :)

PS: I have another question but I figured I'd have to ask on a separate question file.

```
prison_key = False
def test():
    global prison_key
    curr_prompt = "What do you do?"
    print curr_prompt
    choice = raw_input("> ").lower()
    while "quit" not in choice:
        if "go" in choice:
            if "cellar" in choice:
                print "cellar"
            elif "gravel" in choice or "path" in choice:
                print "gravel path"
            elif "prison" in choice and prison_key:
                print "You enter the prison."
            elif "prison" in choice: 
                print "The door is locked."
            else:
                print "Invalid"
        elif "search" in choice:
            if "search" == choice:
                print "invalid"
            elif "prison":
                print "The door is closed."
            elif "bucket" in choice:
               print "The bucket is empty."
            elif "keg" in choice:
                prison_key = True
                print "You find a key."
            elif "door" in choice and ("heavy" in choice or "steel" in choice or "metal" in choice):
                print "It looks like a prison door"
            elif "search door" == choice:
                print "Which one?"
            else:
                print "You find nothing."
        elif "open door" == choice:
                print "which one?" 
        elif "open" in choice:
            if "door" in choice and ("wooden" in choice or "cellar" in choice):
                print "gravel path"
            elif "door" in choice and ("steel" in choice or "metal" in choice or "door" in choice or "heavy" in choice or "prison" in choice) and prison_key:
                print "You open the prison"
            elif "door" in choice and ("steel" in choice or "metal" in choice or "door" in choice or "heavy" in choice or "prison" in choice):
                print "the door is locked"
            elif "prison" in choice and prison_key:
                print "You enter the prison."
            elif "prison" in choice:
                print "the door is locked."
            else:
                print "invalid"
        elif "drink" in choice and "wine" in choice:
            print "You alcoholic."
        else:
            print "invalid"
        print curr_prompt
        choice = raw_input("> ").lower()
    exit(0)

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

so found your problem. In the elif condition for

```
elif "door" in choice and ("steel" in choice or "metal" in choice or "door" in choice or "heavy" in choice or "prison" in choice):
```

You are checking for door again, and thus it passes the if condition.
Same applies for this condition also

```
elif "door" in choice and ("steel" in choice or "metal" in choice or "door" in choice or "heavy" in choice or "prison" in choice) and prison_key:                 

    print "the door is locked"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is that you put `"door" in choice` in the second aprt of your `and` clause:

```
elif "door" in choice and ("steel" in choice or "metal" in choice or "door" in choice or "heavy" in choice or "prison" in choice) and prison_key:
            print "You open the prison"
```

The same applies for the next `elif`.

Nice project btw.

Comment: Oh my gosh !! DUH ! Sorry for this post I should've taken a quick break and re-read my code carefully before posting ! Thanks a lot Anurag and Thomas for the input anyways !